# How can I disable autocorrect for some languages in my keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, gboard

I speak more than one language, and so I have set up my keyboard app ([Gboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin)) with multiple languages, each with its own keyboard layout. I like the fact that autocorrect is enabled in English, I find this feature very useful. However, in the other languages, the autocorrect is terrible and I find it frustrating.

How can I turn off autocorrect just for non-English languages? If this is not possible using Gboard, are there other keyboard apps that have this feature? I welcome answers about any keyboard app.

Answer (score 2):

The keyboard that comes with Samsung phones has this feature.

You can switch keyboards by pressing the little keyboard icon in the navigation bar, or by opening Settings, General Management, Language and Input, On-screen Keyboard.

You can configure the Samsung keyboard like this:

- Open its settings by going to Settngs, General Management, Language and Input, On-screen Keyboard, Samsung Keyboard.
- Open Languages and Types, and add the languages that you want to add.
- Go back to the Samsung Keyboard settings
- Open Auto Replace, and enable auto replace just for the languages that you want to enable it for.

[image: Screenshot]

I don't think it is possible to install the Samsung Keyboard on other types of Android phones.